# How to change number of cores in spark?

Tags: apache-spark

I have the following code

```
import com.datastax.spark.connector._
sc.cassandraTable("test", "hello").cassandraCount
```

This take about an 1hr 30mins to finish but during the process it produces the following output

[Stage 0:>     (12 + 2) / 26674]

where 26674 is the total number of tasks
and 12 are the completed tasks
**The most important one in the number 2 which is the number of tasks that can run in parallel other words max number of cores this application can use is 2. so my big question is How to change this ?**

I have 1 spark master node and 2 spark worker nodes 
Each Spark worker node has 4vCPUs and 16GB RAM (m4.xlarge).

I tried messing around with different values for the following flags

--executor-cores  --total-executor-cores --num-executors

**but I wasn't able to change 2 to something higher** Any ideas?

I use Spark Stand alone cluster

Comment: What is `--master` ? Hope you are not running on default one.

Comment: there is no --master right? just "master". Spark "master" node

Comment: When start shell or submit Spark app you might have specified `--master`

Comment: I am using a standalone cluster so I don't specify that flag along with spark-shell

Comment: as you are not specifying master, it will execute in the same machine. Try starting master and slaves then pass master url to spark-shell. [spark-standalone](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/spark-standalone.html#starting-a-cluster-manually)

Comment: verify  `sc.cassandraTable("test", "hello").isLocal` returns true of false

Comment: isLocal is not a member of com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.CassandraTableScanRDD

Comment: I am running spark-shell in the same machine as spark master and spark master is in sync with spark workers

Comment: Try passing `--master spark://MASTER_IP:PORT` to spark-shell

Comment: It actually did something! it went from 2 to 4 so now it looks like this 
[Stage 0:======> (3119 + 4) / 26639]

Comment: But how can I change this 4 to 8 or some other number?

Comment: `spark-shell --master spark://MASTER_IP:PORT --executor-cores 4 --num-executors 2`

Comment: That didn't change anything. It still kept it to 4

Comment: I also tried --executor-cores 8. It gave me the following message "WARN TaskSchedulerImpl: Initial job has not accepted any resources; check your cluster UI to ensure that workers are registered and have sufficient resources"

Comment: It's because you have 4 cores only and 2 machines

Comment: [Stage 0:======> (3119 + 4) / 26639] so 4 here is number of tasks executing in parallel. I keep hearing you can oversubscribe and change that number but I dont know how

Comment: even google says you can use SPARK_WORKER_CORES to oversubscribe I edited conf/spark-env.sh and restarted all workers but it still didnt work inside spark-shell so I guess I am missing something

Comment: look at this http://blog.insightdatalabs.com/spark-cluster-step-by-step/
ctrl + f SPARK_WORKER_CORES

Comment: `SPARK_WORKER_CORES` is another way of setting `--num-executors` or `spark.executor.cores`. the default value for this property is **All available cores**

Answer (score 0):

`export SPARK_WORKER_CORES=12` in conf/spark-env.sh is the way to oversubscribe to number of cores that can run in parallel